# OTP validation with mongodb and react js

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb

In react:
login with mobile number store that number in database if not exist in that database.
then otp page. vailidated
then go to next page with email verification validated
redirect user to login page if mobile number exist in database
if its not exist in database redirect him to singup page
using mongodb database
within the same table of database.
how should I do it. its client requirement please help

expecting it to check first weather it number exist in database

Comment: You can't achieve above mentioned functionalities using React only, You will need a backend server which will handle API requests. You have to create seperate pages for Login, Sign Up etc. on React side and you have to call API into the same, You can check all the validations on the backend server like user is exist or not and all that, Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.